# Datetimepicker block earlier date

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have two `dateTimePicker` and I would like to know if it is possible to do something like this. I choose date at first one and in second one it will automatically block possibility of choosing earlier date than the first one? If so, how can I achieve it?

Comment: In Jquery, on change event of first date picker you can set the selected date as min date for the second date picker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the first DateTimePicker's `ValueChanged` event and set the second DateTimePicker's [MinDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate.aspx) property there.

```
private void firstDateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //add code to validate selected value (handle errors etc...)
    //...        

    secondDateTimePicker.MinDate = firstDateTimePicker.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ValueChanged` event of the the first dateTimePicker and set the MinDate of dateTimePicker2 to the value of the dateTimePicker1.

```
dateTimePicker2.MinDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
```